# Call specific excel cells in Shell commands with VBA

Tags: windows, vba, excel, batch-file

I have a bat file that I wish to execute from VBA. In my workbook is the name of the batch file : test.bat. Since test.bat and my workbook will change folders I am using

```
ThisWorkbook.Path
```

to always have the current directory.

However I am unable to insert the cell which contains the batch file name in the shell commands after putting ThisWorbook.Path.

Here is my code so far :

```
Sub helpme ()

Shell "cmd.exe /k cd " & ThisWorkbook.Path & Range("B41")

End Sub
```

Note that with just

```
Shell "cmd.exe /k cd " & ThisWorkbook.Path
```

the code opens a cmd window and sets it to the directory of the workbook, so it's just a question of inserting the "test.bat" string contained in cell B41 to execute the bat file.

Thank you very much for your help, I hope it's an easy fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to imtheman's answer: if your workbook path contains spaces then you should wrap the path in quotes

```
Sub helpme ()

    'Shell "cmd.exe /k cd """ & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B41") & """"
    'if you just want to run the bat file...
    Shell """" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B41") & """"

End Sub
```

Comment: @imtheman@Tim Williams Thank you for your quick responses, however I can't seem to get it to work, your code Tim Williams has a syntax problem; I tried variations of it but it either doesn't have proper syntax or the command prompt opens with the message "the system cannot find the path specified" or "the directory name is invalid"

Comment: There was a missing `&` - fixed

Comment: Yes i thought it was missing so I tried it as you put it, but it says the directory name is invalid. Maybe it's because I need 2 separate commands; one that sets the cmd box to the correct directory and another that then executes the test.bat ? Would you know how to do that ? Because i think that your code means it's trying to set the directory  all the way to the test.bat which it can't do naturally...

Comment: If you just want to run the bat file you don't need the `cd`

Comment: ...unless whatever is in your bat file makes assumptions about the current directory being the one where your bat file is located...

Comment: Thankfully it doesn't, so that did solve my problem :) Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 1):

`ThisWorkbook.Path` doesn't have a trailing `\`

```
Sub helpme ()

Shell "cmd.exe /k cd " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Range("B41")

End Sub
```